# How to divide the changelog.yaml into subsections?

Tags: yaml, liquibase

I would like to separate each change of the databaseChangeLog in YAML format into its own file (again YAML) and include/import it somehow. It should be in way such that I can use a FileSystemAccessor or ClassPathAccessor to load it again.

Is there some example how to do that?

Thanks,
Dieter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I found this on the liquibase repo:

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/test/resources/liquibase/parser/core/yaml/doubleNestedChangeLog.yaml

It is an example how you can separate your yaml files analog to the xml as shown by SteveDonies link.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is described at https://www.liquibase.org/bestpractices.html

The example given shows XML formatted changelogs, but the basic idea would be the same for YAML formatted changelogs.

Leave me a comment and I can generate a sample in YAML.